# Rendering a cube in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt

I'm trying to program a rotaing cube. Therefore I generate a cube using my `make_cube` method. Unfortunatly some faces of the cube don't get rendered. I tried a lot I don't understand why the cube is not "extruded" fully. Here is my code for generating the cube:

```
def make_cube(self):
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0)
    #front
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, 0.0)
    # back
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, -0.2)
    # right
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.0)
    # left
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, 0.0)
    # top
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, -0.2)
    # bottom
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, -0.2)
    GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, -0.2)
```

Comment: Missing glBegin(GL_LINES) / GL_END ?

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glBegin.3G.xml

Comment: No, they are included in the calling method: glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS) make_cube() glEnd()

Comment: That code seems to be fine. Does the problem appear when rotating the cube? Then you should post some extra code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by culling. Your front and back side differs only in z component, that means one is rendered clock-wise another counter-cw and same for every else opposite sides.

```
#front
GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, 0.0)
GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.0)
GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, 0.0)
# back
GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.0, -0.2)
GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.0, -0.2)
GL.glVertex3d(0.2, 0.2, -0.2)
GL.glVertex3d(0.0, 0.2, -0.2)
```

OpenGL culls off back faces to improve perfomace, however you have to have all your primitives CW or CCW.

Look at [glCullFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml) and [glFrontFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml).